Est-ce qu'on dit le nombre de voitures en entrée et "celui" en sortie "sont égaux" ou "est égal"?
Est-ce qu'on dit le nombre de voitures en entrée et ""celui"" en sortie ""sont égaux"" ou ""est égal""? et sans/avec "celui" ou bien "ceux"? Et pourquoi?

Il serait plus clair de dire « Le nombre de voitures en entrée est égal à celui des voitures en sortie », et en plus ça règle ton problème.

Une seule chose ne peut pas être égale en tant que telle. Il lui faut une deuxième pour que la comparaison soit possible.

Avec les contraintes de la question, le pluriel s'impose.

Le nombre de voitures en entrée et celui en sortie sont égaux.

ou

Les nombres de voitures en entrée et en sortie sont égaux.

On compare deux nombres différents, deux mesures distinctes même si elles ont la même valeur.
None a proposé une phrase plus claire en commentaire:

Le nombre de voitures en entrée est égal à celui des voitures en sortie.

On pourrait dire aussi :

Il entre autant de voitures qu'il n'en sort.


Merci beaucoup de votre réponse.
